# Where can i get the php5apache2_4.dll for Windows?

Tags: php5, apache-2.4

I got a new laptop with Windows 7 and want to set up a php+mysql develop environment.
Thus, I downloaded `httpd_2.4.3-netware-bin` and install `Apache 2.4` successfully.
Then I got `php-5.4.10-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip` and unpack it . But I can't find `php5apache2_4.dll` in it. (I need put it in `httpd.conf` , Am I right?)
So I went to Google for it, but I got nothing.
Where can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which package you have downloaded but the working package can be found at windows.php.net/download/. You have to download the vc6 version, non-thread-safe.

P.S if you don't find the  `php5apache2_4.dll` you downloaded the wrong package, I repeat you need the vc6 non thread safe version.

P.P.S: If you want to simplify all the process I suggest you to use WAMP, this do all the tricks, installing a working apache php server without requires tons of googling. www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Thank you very much , I'll go to try the `php5.dll` instead . If it do not work, I'll try the WAMP.

Comment: No dude sorry, I edit the answer, you need the php5apache2_4.dll ( orphp5apache2_2.dll according to your apache version), if you don't find it you have the wrong package. vc6 version, non-thread-safe the file is named php-5.2.17-nts-Win32-VC6-x86.zip

Comment: Oh. I tried `php5.dll` and it is does not work. And I just finish the downloading of `WAMP` . Then I saw you before I do any uninstall and install. You said that I need a vc6 version package , is that means I can not use `PHP 5.3` or later?

Comment: Exactly, If you want to use php5.3 or later you can't use apache on your environment. Quote from php site:
If PHP is used with IIS then choose PHP 5.3 VC9 Non Thread Safe or PHP 5.2 VC6 Non Thread Safe;
If PHP is used with IIS7 or greater and PHP 5.3+, then the VC9 binaries of PHP should be used.
If PHP is used with Apache 1 or Apache 2 then choose PHP 5.3 VC6 or PHP 5.2 VC6.

Comment: To complete the answer I suggest you to follow the php5 official guide to install it: php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php

Comment: Ahhhhh... I see that in left sidebar , thank you . But when I googling for the dll, I got some `php5apache2_4.dll`s for from `PHP 5.4.0` to `PHP 5.4.9` .How it works?